# sap-ui-core.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)send @ sap-ui-core.js:12

Tags: sapui5

I'm following online tutorial to display data, but I got an error

> sap-ui-core.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
>   status of 404 (Not Found)send @ sap-ui-core.js:12

While debugging I found that `i18n_en.properties` and `i18n_en_US.properties` files are not found. In my application i18n folder have only `i18n.properties` file. I'm using SAPUI5 template in web IDE trail

Please help  to resolve the issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

those errors can be ignored. each just says that there is a internationalisation file missing. e.g. the `i18n_en.properties`. this file would contain the english texts of an application. located in the `i18n` folder.

as long as there is no need for internatisation of the application those errors can be ignored. to remedy those errors it's necessary to create the `i18n` files of the errors in the `i18n` folder. in this case `i18n_en.properties` and `i18n_en_US.properies`.